# in Twilio Studio, how can I save the user input from a "Gather input on call"

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

Let me be clear - I'm trying to do this using Twilio STUDIO - not coding. I have a complete IVR built and working, but I can't figure out how to save the selections the caller inputs (DTMF). Is there a simple plugin or addon that can save user input?

Comment: @philnash can you help?

Comment: Oops, sorry I didn't see this notification until now. I think Matt's answer below is correct, Studio can't save things itself, so if you want to store the selections of a user you will need to make a request to your own server with a Function or HTTP request.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about '[split based on keys](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials/how-to-build-an-ivr#split-based-on-keys)' this will let you change menus, call etc when a user presses a key?  Have a read of the tutorial. However, if you are trying to save the data, you would need to use a [http request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library#http-request) or write a [function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library#run-function). Both involve coding.